# ASP.NET HttpHandler for x3d / MIME type

Tags: asp.net, web-config, x3dom

I use [x3dom](http://www.x3dom.org/) to render x3d files. I use the inline loading:

```
 <inline url="/myfile.x3d" render="true" bboxcenter="0,0,0" bboxsize="-1,-1,-1" load="true" namespacename=""></inline>
```

With `.txt` as file extension it works. With `.x3d` it doesn't. So I added a `HttpHandler` to my `web.config`

```
  <add verb="*" path="*.x3d" type="x3dHandler" />
```

Without success...

Comment: I assume you need to [add a MIME type in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx) for `.x3d` in addition to the handler. It appears the correct MIME type should be `model/x3d+xml`.

Comment: So if I have no access to the Server Config (Azure) I have no chance?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll probably want to check with Azure Support. Anyway, what's wrong with using .txt if it works?

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers who got the same problem - it may not be only in MIME-type.

If you want to show .x3d simply with url in `<inline>` tag you may want to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with whitelist domain to your host serving .x3d files.

In my case (Django framework instead of ASP.NET) I used https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers package and it worked like a charm.